# Reading message from properties file in spring4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am facing an issue in reading the properties file in spring mvc4. To read messages I have added following in spring-servlet.xml file located under WEB-INF folder.

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.restful.producer" /> 

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="location">
      <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
      </property>
      <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
```

In my controller class,

```
@Value("${MSG}") 
private String msg;
```

i am getting msg as null. Please helpout me how to load properties file. My appilcation.properties file is available in classpath only.

I am using Spring-4.0.5

Thank you

Comment: is the controller class annotated with @Component ? also is the controller class within 'com.test.restful.producer' ?

Comment: Yes Artem Bilan. the controller is in the same package and i used @component annotation as well. but still it is not working.

Comment: for me i had to put my properties files in the resource folder, then make the file accessable via controler. After that reading in variables became easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this xml for creating properties bean.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
  p:location="classpath:propertyFile.properties" name="propertiesBean"/>
```

Or go for non xml version as below

```
@PropertySource("classpath:propertyFile.properties")
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```